# Check the radio button that corresponds to the post being edited, if there are validation errors, after "update" is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I have a view where it shows in each radio button a post name that corresponds to each post that exist in database. And below there is also  a radio button to create a new post "create new post".

When a radio button that corresponds to an existing post is clicked the form fields are populated with that post info. When the radio button "create new post" is clicked the form fields become empty so the user can introduce info to create a new post.

If the user selects the radio button "Create post" and fill the form fields and click "create" and he filled some field incorrectly, for example with a incorrect date format, the fields are not cleared so the user dont need to introduce them again. This works fine.

**Issue:** But when a user select some radio button that corresponds to a existing post, the form fields are populated with the post stored info in the database using JS. If the user change some info of the form, for example the date field, and introduce a date with a incorrect format, it appears an error, but the "create post" radio button becomes checked, and so instead of the user continue in the context of edit the selected post he changes for a context to create a new post because the radio button "create new post" becomes checked.

Do you know how to fix that?

Form with each post radio button and "create new post" radio button and the other form fields:

```
 <form id="editposts" method="post" 
      action="{{route('posts.update', ['post_id' => $post->id])}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {{csrf_field()}}
  <div>
    @foreach($posts as $post)
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input radio" type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="{{ $post->id }}" id="{{$post->id}}">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        {{$post->title}}
      </label>
    </div>
    @endforeach
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <input checked class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radiobutton" id="create_post"
           value="create_post">
    <label class="form-check-label">
      Create post
    </label>
  </div>

  <!-- form fields, here is the name but are more like description, etc -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Post title</label>
    <input  type="text" required class="form-control" value="{{ old('title') }}" name="title" id="tile">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" id="poststore" value="Create"/>
  <input type="submit" id="postupdate" value="Update"/>
</form>
```

JS to populate the form fields based on selected post and to change form action based on radio button selected:

```
var posts = {!!  $post !!}
$("#postupdate").hide();
$("input[name='radiobutton']").click(function() {
  let id = $(this).attr("id");
  if (id == "create_post") {
    $("#postupdate").hide();
    $("#poststore").show();
    $("#editposts").attr('action', '{{route('posts.store', ['post_id' => $post->id])}}');
    $("input[name='title']").val("");
    ...
  } else {
    $("#postupdate").show();
    $("#poststore").hide();
    $("#editposts").attr('action', '{{route('posts.update', ['post_id' => $post->id])}}');
    let data = posts.find(e => e.id == id) || {
      title: "",
      ...

    };
      $("input[name='title']").val(data.title);
      ...
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check the value of the old input with `name='radiobutton'` after the error submits and if the value matches the post id mark it as `checked`, in case the old radiobutton value is create_post you check the create new post radio button.

You can read more about [old inputs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#old-input) from the official Laravel docs.

Like this:

```
 <form id="editposts" method="post" 
      action="{{route('posts.update', ['post_id' => $post->id])}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {{csrf_field()}}
  <div>
    @foreach($posts as $post)
    <div class="form-check">
      <input {{ (old('radiobutton') && old('radiobutton') == $post->id) ? 'checked' : '' }} class="form-check-input radio" type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="{{ $post->id }}" id="{{$post->id}}">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        {{$post->title}}
      </label>
    </div>
    @endforeach
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <input {{ (old('radiobutton') && old('radiobutton') == 'create_post') ? 'checked' : '' }} class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radiobutton" id="create_post"
           value="create_post">
    <label class="form-check-label">
      Create post
    </label>
  </div>

  <!-- form fields, here is the name but are more like description, etc -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Post title</label>
    <input  type="text" required class="form-control" value="{{ old('title') }}" name="title" id="tile">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" id="poststore" value="Create"/>
  <input type="submit" id="postupdate" value="Update"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it shows an error "Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression". Do you know why?

Comment: I change to use "!=null" like "{{ (old('radiobutton') != null && old('radiobutton') == $post->id) ? 'checked' : '' }}" but same issue, the "create post" radio button becomes checked if update button is clicked and there are validation errors.

Comment: @AdamK it was missing a `)`, sorry.

Comment: Okay, forgot you don't need to use isset() on old() inputs :)

Comment: Thanks, now dont appears any error but I get the same issue, for example some existing post is selected, for example the post "title test", the form fields are populated with that post info, the date field is updated with a date in a incorrect format and "update" is clicked, it appears a validation error saying that the date is incorrect but the "create new post" radio button becomes checked instead of "title test" radio button.

Comment: Make sure you send the radio button input to the controller.

Comment: public function update(Request $request, $id){

        $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required|string',
           ...
        ]);

        $post = Post::find($request->radiobutton);

        $post->title = $request->title;
 
        $post->save();

        return redirect()->back();
    }

Comment: The post is found based on the radio button on the update method, it is that?

Comment: Check the value of the `$request->radiobutton` when you check it and submit.

Comment: Then the condition should work, try to cast string on the comparator, old('radiobutton') == (string)$post->id , but I don't know what's wrong right now. Try to print the old('radiobutton') value with {{old('radiobutton')}}

Comment: With "old('radiobutton') == (string)$post->id"  it shows the same issue, the {{old('radiobutton')} seems that is empty "".

Comment: Try `return redirect()->back()->withInput();`

Comment: Thanks, but it shows the same issue the radio button becomes checked.

Comment: It works but only if the input "create new post" dont have the "checked".